# What other ways can you install deb files

Tags: apt, 20.04, update-manager, python3, deb

A while ago I messed up my computer trying to fix something else (it's already figured out) and deleted some core files, which makes my computer unable to update and install via apt-get. I know that I was making an ignorant mistake with that action, I do not need reminding.

When I try to update here is the result:

```
pluto@pluto-Ubunu-Mate:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for pluto: 
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                     
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]     
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]      
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mutlaqja/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease             
Hit:7 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                           
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]   
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [493 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [24.5 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,036 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [58.2 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stellarium/stellarium-releases/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [283 kB]
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [787 kB]
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [578 kB]
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [330 kB]
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [17.8 kB]
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]
Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1,768 B]
Fetched 3,941 kB in 1s (2,911 kB/s)                                   
sh: 1: /usr/lib/cnf-update-db: not found
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

When I try to upgrade here is the result:

```
pluto@pluto-Ubunu-Mate:~$ sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for pluto: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core : Depends: python3-distupgrade (= 1:20.04.31) but 1:20.04.30 is installed
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk : Depends: python3-distupgrade (= 1:20.04.31) but 1:20.04.30 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

The above was to show the damage to my system (I intend to fix it better at a later date). Now for the real issue, chrome. I got a message from chrome saying it needing to be updated, but because of my computer's issues, google said I needed to reinstall chrome. The only file that google chrome provides is a Debian file, which I cannot currently install due to my computer's issues.

When I try to install the deb chrome file:

```
pluto@pluto-Ubunu-Mate:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for pluto: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
```

I am not an expert on the different ways to download, install, upgrade/update my computer, I am only aware of the basics. I am aware of my mistake of messing with my computer using poor practices, that is why I am asking. Please be more understanding. I would like to be able to reinstall chrome so that I can use it before I am able to properly reinstall.

Specs:

Ubuntu Version-Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Gnome Version 3.36.8

Comment: You have beaten your system with a `root` stick. Backup your user data, reinstall, and learn how to manage packages `man apt synaptic apt-cache`. Learn what your system does before changing it. You are not following good practices.

Comment: waltinator I am looking for a smaller solution before I can 'reset my computer' aka reinstall the os. Nmath I will rephrase my question, thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You broke your APT package management system. It is in an inconsistent state. As long as it is broken, you will not be able to install or update any software that is installed through the APT package management system, i.e., involving `.deb` installation files.

There is no "different" system to install `.deb` files. By design, `.deb` files are installed through the APT package management system, also these that you downloaded manually and install using `dpkg -i` or `apt`.

The basis is broken. You first need to fix the basis. You cannot upgrade your current Chrome installation before the APT package management system is coherent again.

Fixing a broken package system is not always easy, and there is no one-fits-all procedure. See some earlier questions on broken packages: [How to Fix Broken Packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285605/how-to-fix-broken-packages), [Cannot fix broken packages (apt-get -f install doesn't work)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/899497/cannot-fix-broken-packages-apt-get-f-install-doesnt-work), [Can't fix broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116788/cant-fix-broken-packages), ...